# Enable UWSGI caching only when Cache-Control headers are set

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, http-caching

I'd like to use Nginx to cache a Uwsgi app. The app sets the `Cache-Control` header for some requests. The Nginx-cache should only be enabled for those requests and respect the `max-age` condition.

So I'm trying to set `uwsgi_no_cache 1` for requests where upstream doesn't set `Cache-Control`. And `uwsgi_no_cache 0` for requests where upstream does set the `Cache-Control` header.

However, this does not work:

```
set $no_cache 1;
if ($sent_http_cache_control) {
    set $no_cache 0;
}
uwsgi_no_cache $no_cache;
```

The problem lies with `$sent_http_cache_control`, unfortunately it does not reflect the header set upstream.

Is there a way of only enabling caching in Nginx when `Cache-Control` is set upstream?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `$http_cache_control` instead of `$sent_http_cache_control` ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani `$http_cache_control` is the query-header. I want the response-header from the upstream UWSGI-Process.

Comment: Then it should be `$upstream_http_cache_control`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks! Looks like a solution. Want to write an answer for the bounty-karma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For headers returned by the upstream service you will need to use the `$upstream_http_` prefix

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_http_

So in your case it should be `$upstream_http_cache_control`